# What is the difference between {...} and Object when logging data in the Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log, google-chrome-console

I was just logging some user data in the Google Chrome console and the console was rendering the data for different users differently. When the user object is closed, some users are rendered as `{...}` and some users are rendered as `Object`. When I open a user object to view all the user properties, the properties are all the same between users.

```
133393: Object
5664431: Object
5664525: {…}
6580115: {…}
6580437: {…}
6582762: {…}
6583514: Object
6583554: {…}
6583768: {…}
6583985: Object
6584137: Object
6591129: {…}
6593402: Object
6593977: Object
6623044: Object
```

Why is this happening? Does this mean that there is some different in the data structure between certain users?

Comment: Maybe you had the console open/closed at different times throughout your tests? The output inside a closed console will be different from the output when it's open.